# Automate browser and native app

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation

I want to use Appium to automate the scenario below on Android

1. First open a web page in Chrome. The web page contains a
   registration form
2. Fill the form then click the submit button
3. The submit button open my native app via the uri (the same behavior
   as we open the Google Play by clicking on a link market://...)
4. Finally interact with the app

I could make the automation for step 1 to 3 but stucked at step 4.

Is this possible with Appium? Is there any other testing framework which can automate the scenario like that?

Comment: What happens after step 3? Appium logs after step 3 might help understand what's going wrong.

Comment: After step 3, the app is opened but the function driver.findElement(By.id("my_button_id")) is not working

Comment: Please edit in your appium logs from that point of time until the end. Feel free to edit out any app specific identifiers, if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to changing from the webview context to the native app's own context. This is done in Java by using the command `driver.context("NATIVE_APP");`

To view all available contexts use `driver.getContextHandles();`, which returns a `Set<String>` with all available contexts.

Native context is always called "NATIVE_APP" and webviews usually are indexed as "WEBVIEW_0", "WEBVIEW_1" and so on.

All interactions to the app that are not related to a webview directly, will usually need to be done while in "NATIVE_APP" context.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you have timeout exception, just change your code from `driver.find_element(By.id("my_button_id"))`
to

`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda:driver.find_element(By.id("my_button_id")))`